# Visual Studio Code intellisense not working at solution level

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am new to `.NET Core`.
I created two projects in the sol directory like this

```
 Sol
   hw(which is a console application)
   hwlib(which is a lib used in hw)
   .vscode
      launch.json
      tasks.json
```

when I open hw and hwlib with visual studio code then intellisense works fine. But when I open Sol with visual studio code intellisense doesn't works.

What am i doing wrong?